# Run a RESTfull service in Nunit for integration testing purposes

Tags: wcf, rest, nunit, integration-testing

I am creating a restful service in .NET where i define an interface decorated with WebGet and WebInvoke attributes and host it as a WCF service. To make internal company consumption of the service easier i am creating a Proxy class that implements the service interface and executes the restful request and responses using the REST interface defined on the service.

What i want to be able to do is test that this proxy class hits the service implementation over HTTP in the correct way. This would be to catch any breaking changes in the interface between it and the proxy. I don't know how to do this. I think i need to spin up the webservice but i kind of imagine that i will need to host this in a webserver, if so is there an in memory web server i could use. I don't think i could use IIS express as i'm running VS2008. Once i have the service running my proxy should be able to talk to it quite easily as long as i know the URI, right?

Or is there another way that i can test my proxy implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you would use [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com) then you could host the service inside unit test. I have done few integration tests using that technique. I'm only suggesting WCF Web API because you are talking about REST services and WCF Web API has been developed exactly for making it easier to build REST based services. If you must use pure WCF with proxy classes (proxies are not needed with WCF Web API) then you can ignore this answer.